# Dynamic Sites module randomly crashing the Site Resolver

Tags: module

### The issue

I have the Dynamic Sites module installed and configured on a single instance 8.1 (rev 160519). It runs fine most of the time. But as the customer is adding sites to it, once or twice a day. The site crashes out hard with the error below. The only thing that resolves the error is an IIS RESET or touching the web.config.

### The config

The config is here to save space. https://gist.github.com/dnstommy/d72f89e4f7b48fc6d858fe290bddc679

### What I know

The issue always is proceeded by a publish of a new site item. Many site items have been published and do not cause this issue. Its random, maybe a timing issue.

### The error

> 5252 13:54:18 INFO  AUDIT (sitecore\matthew): Publish item now:
>   web:/sitecore/system/Modules/Dynamic Sites/Sites/Amite, language: en,
>   version: 1, id: {478FF98A-3303-4D43-ABBE-9C5D97796003}
>
> 5252 13:54:18INFO  AUDIT (sitecore\matthew): [Publishing]: Starting to process 1
>   publishing options
>
> 10140 13:54:19 ERROR Application error. Exception:
>   System.NullReferenceException Message: Object reference not set to an
>   instance of an object. Source: Sitecore.Kernel    at
>   Sitecore.Sites.SiteContextFactory.GetSites()    at
>   Sitecore.ExperienceExplorer.Business.Helpers.SettingsHelper.IsEnabledForSite(String
>   siteName)    at
>   Sitecore.ExperienceExplorer.Business.Helpers.PageModeHelper.get_IsExperienceMode()
>   at
>   Sitecore.ExperienceExplorer.Business.Pipelines.HttpRequestProcessed.RetrieveRenderingsPipeline.Process(HttpRequestArgs
>   args)    at (Object , Object[] )    at
>   Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipeline.Run(PipelineArgs args)    at
>   Sitecore.Nexus.Web.HttpModule.(Object , EventArgs )    at
>   System.Web.HttpApplication.SyncEventExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
>   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step,
>   Boolean& completedSynchronously)
>
> 9408 13:54:19 ERROR Application error. Exception:
>   System.NullReferenceException Message: Object reference not set to an
>   instance of an object. Source: Sitecore.Kernel    at
>   Sitecore.Sites.SiteContextFactory.GetSites()    at
>   Sitecore.Sites.SiteContextFactory.GetSiteContext(String hostName,
>   String fullPath, Int32 portNumber)    at
>   Sitecore.Pipelines.HttpRequest.SiteResolver.ResolveSiteContext(HttpRequestArgs
>   args)    at
>   Sitecore.Pipelines.HttpRequest.SiteResolver.Process(HttpRequestArgs
>   args)    at (Object , Object[] )    at
>   Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipeline.Run(PipelineArgs args)    at
>   Sitecore.Nexus.Web.HttpModule.(Object , EventArgs )    at
>   System.Web.HttpApplication.SyncEventExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
>   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step,
>   Boolean& completedSynchronously)

### Publishing error at the same time.

> 5252 13:54:19 ERROR An error during Publish Pipeline Process Queue
>   execution. Exception: System.NullReferenceException Message: Object
>   reference not set to an instance of an object. Source: Sitecore.Kernel
>   at Sitecore.Sites.SiteContextFactory.GetSites()    at
>   Sitecore.Sites.SiteContextFactory.GetSiteNames()    at
>   Sitecore.Configuration.Factory.GetSiteInfoList()    at
>   Sitecore.Caching.ItemCache.RemoveItemFromFilterCaches(ID itemId)    at
>   System.EventHandler 1.Invoke(Object sender, TEventArgs e)    at
>   Sitecore.Data.Engines.EngineCommand 2.RaiseEvent[TArgs](EventHandler 1
>   handlers, Func 2 argsCreator)    at
>   Sitecore.Data.Engines.EngineCommand 2.Execute()    at
>   Sitecore.Data.Engines.DataEngine.SaveItem(Item item)    at
>   Sitecore.Data.Managers.ItemProvider.SaveItem(Item item)    at
>   Sitecore.Data.Managers.PipelineBasedItemProvider.ExecuteAndReturnResult[TArgs,TResult](String
>   pipelineName, String pipelineDomain, Funcc1 pipelineArgsCreator,
>   Func 1 fallbackResult)    at
>   Sitecore.Data.Managers.PipelineBasedItemProvider.SaveItem(Item item)
>   at Sitecore.Data.Items.ItemEditing.AcceptChanges(Boolean
>   updateStatistics, Boolean silent)    at
>   Sitecore.Data.Items.EditContext.Dispose()    at
>   Sitecore.Publishing.PublishHelper.CopyToTarget(Item sourceVersion)
>   at Sitecore.Publishing.PublishHelper.PublishVersionToTarget(Item
>   sourceVersion, Item targetItem, Boolean targetCreated)    at
>   Sitecore.Publishing.Pipelines.PublishItem.PerformAction.Process(PublishItemContext
>   context)    at (Object , Object[] )    at
>   Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipeline.Run(PipelineArgs args)    at
>   Sitecore.Publishing.Pipelines.PublishItem.PublishItemPipeline.Run(PublishItemContext
>   context)    at
>   Sitecore.Publishing.Pipelines.Publish.ProcessQueue.ProcessPublishingCandidate(PublishingCandidate
>   entry, PublishContext context, List 1& referrers, List`1& children)
>   at
>   Sitecore.Publishing.Pipelines.Publish.ProcessQueue.ProcessPublishingCandidate(PublishingCandidate
>   entry, PublishContext context)    at
>   Sitecore.Publishing.Pipelines.Publish.ProcessQueue.ProcessEntries(IEnumerable 1
>   entries, PublishContext context)    at
>   Sitecore.Publishing.Pipelines.Publish.ProcessQueue.ProcessPublishingCandidate(PublishingCandidate
>   entry, PublishContext context)    at
>   Sitecore.Publishing.Pipelines.Publish.ProcessQueue.ProcessEntries(IEnumerable 1
>   entries, PublishContext context)    at
>   Sitecore.Publishing.Pipelines.Publish.ProcessQueue.Process(PublishContext
>   context)

I turned off auto publish in the dynamic sites config and I got this error after an hour.

[image]

Comment: Base on the stacktrace, it gets null reference when while performing publishing, right?

Comment: Does this one help https://github.com/Vapok/Sitecore.SharedSource.DynamicSites/issues/1 ?

Comment: @HishaamNamooya Yes it does. I added the publishing error to the question above.

Comment: @MarekMusielak Thats does not. The latest config has the website config in it now, labeled as disable.local.

Comment: I haven't used the Dynamic Sites module but what I can say is that the list of SiteInfo is empty. Now, Sitecore tries to get the list of Sites using the `SiteManager.GetSites()`.It may be that Sitecore cannot see the Sites hence returning null. Because there is not null check on the `foreach` from the Sitecore.Kernel.dll. Reason why it is working sometimes is because the SiteInfo list is not null. Maybe increasing the cache may help

Comment: I was directed here. As soon as I get some time, I'll provide a response. As it stands, I can't pinpoint a particular reason. However, what version of the module are you using? Just so I have a reference point. Also, can you tell me how many sites you have, and how frequently the list changes, and do multiple authors change the list at the same time by chace? Thanks!

Comment: Thanks @PeteNavarra The dlls says 1.7, so many thats the issue. The customer is copying in 800 sites right now. Probably moving 2-3 an hour.

Comment: I would consider going to 1.8.  It was updated for 8.1 Update 3.  https://github.com/Vapok/Sitecore.SharedSource.DynamicSites/releases/tag/v1.8-rev160519

Comment: Hi @ChrisAuer, did you ever get to the bottom of this at all? I'm seeing an similar issue with GetSites() throwing that collection error randomly. Refreshing the page fixes it. So it's like the Sites collection is being modified sometimes and breaking if you try and read it at the same time it's being updated.

Comment: @AdamSeabridge No. I ended up making it write to a sites.config file instead. The issue is the sites collection is not locked, nor do I think it can be. So it tries to access it while is being rebuilt. Then the site is dead. This only seemed to be an issue when you have a lot of sites. I could not figure out how SXA did it.

Comment: Ok thanks Chris. I did find this:
https://sitecorerocksblog.wordpress.com/2020/10/07/one-of-our-cd-servers-randomly-stops-displaying-the-sxa-sites/ and the related support patch: https://github.com/SitecoreSupport/Sitecore.Support.352832

which looks like something related to the sites collection cache being cleared on publish end. It seems to create some kind of lock/unlock. Anyway I've gone for using SiteContextFactory.Sites instead of SiteManager - this reads from the sites list in Sitecore config and not prone to cache clearing issues found with with the SiteManger.GetSites() method.